# Vertical alignment of a floated div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center vertically a floated div, [here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4om0czr/)

```css
.wrapper{
    width:250px;
    background-color:red;
}

#SmileImg{
    height:100px;
    width:auto;
}

.textwrapper{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2010/02/147370,xcitefun-smile-4.png" id="SmileImg" />
    <div class="textwrapper">
        <p>Please Smile!</p> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

I do not know how to put the text "Please Smile" vertically centered.

Hope someone will help me. Please be patient I am not an expert!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating elements cannot be vertically aligned, you should either use inline blocks, or set line height equal to image height for your text. One more way is to use "display: table-cell"

example with inline blocks:

```css
.wrapper{
    width:250px;
    background-color:red;
}

#SmileImg{
    height:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.textwrapper{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2010/02/147370,xcitefun-smile-4.png" id="SmileImg" />
    <div class="textwrapper">
        <p>Please Smile!</p> 
    </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display: table`

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
    width:250px;
    background-color:red;
    display: table;
}
.item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#SmileImg{
    height:100px;
    width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
    <img src="http://img.xcitefun.net/users/2010/02/147370,xcitefun-smile-4.png" id="SmileImg" />
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p>Please Smile!</p> 
    </div>       
</div>
```